# Is it possible to register named custom color schemes in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite, altair

I would like to register a custom [Multi-Hue Sequential Color Scheme](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#yellowgreenblue) in vega-lite.

My reading of the documentation is that I can only create `config.range` objects to set custom color scales, but there is no way to expose a function for interpolation thereby eliminating the possibility of a custom scheme.

The Vega specification allows for this using the `vega.scheme` and  `vega.schemeDescretized` [functions](https://github.com/vega/vega-scale/#scheme)

I would like to follow the pattern demonstrated in the `d3-scale-chromatic` ([example here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/master/src/sequential-multi/YlGnBu.js)) but I am unable to find the entry point to do this in vega-lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vega-Lite specifications compile to Vega specification and use Vega runtime to render visualizations.  I think you should be able to use `vega.scheme` and make it work for Vega-Lite too?

Comment: in [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/blob/master/README.md), patching the compiled vega spec accordingly should also work for this purpose.